# Are you wishful for bees?

Tags: wordplay, letters, quote

Start with the phrase `Are you wishful for bees?` and perform the following steps in some order to find **a famous phrase**:

- Add a letter
- Add a word
- Break a word in two
- Combine two words
- Rearrange the words
- Remove two letters from one word

*Note: adding/removing punctuation is not included in the steps.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Are you wishful for bees?**

```
Remove two letters from one word
```

> Are you wishful for be <s>***es***</s>

```
Break a word in two
```

> Are you wish**] [**ful for be

```
Add a word
```

> Are you wish ful for be ***what***

```
Add a letter
```

> ***C***are you wish ful for be what

```
Rearrange the words
```

> ***Be*** care ***ful what*** you wish for

```
Combine two words
```

> **Be careful what you wish for!**

Answer (score 9):

Are you wishful for bees?

•Add a letter

> **D**are you wishful for bees?

•Add a word

> Dare you wishful **some** for bees?

•Break a word in two

> Dare you wish ful some for bees?

•Combine two words

> Dare you wish fulsome for bees?

•Rearrange the words

> Dare you wish for fulsome bees?

•Remove two letters from one word

> Dare you wish for fulsome B's?

The phrase is of course

> the despairing cry of the flatchested maiden before being enhanced.....